# How to use RainX Windshield Crack Repair?

Tags: windshield

I bought the RainX Windshield Crack Repair kit from Walmart, blue and yellow kit.

I read over the  instructions, and watched a video on YT, but since *this is the first time I am performing a windshield crack repair*, I was wondering (from those who have performed this procedure before) what I should particularly focus on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: So, what do the instructions say? And why do you think they are inadequate?